# Getting date column from database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field `Publish_on` in my mysql database table. It stores the date and time when a post was added.

I am not able to get the publish dates. Instead, the output I get is today's date, even if the post belongs to other dates.

```
$id = (int) ($_GET['postid']);

$result = mysqli_query("
    SELECT Publish_on 
      FROM `post_head` 
     WHERE `post_id` = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'
");

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row['Publish_on']);

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
```

Comment: what is the output of your query?

Comment: today's date and current time @NitinP

Comment: Can you please try $date   = date_create(strtotime($row['Publish_on']));

Comment: its working fine ... Please check live demo : https://eval.in/682415

Comment: What's the point in the `$id` variable? You never use it.

Comment: @RJParikh you can't say it's working because you don't know what's in the `Publish_on` column. It could be entries like "Yesterday" or something - we haven't been given that information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `mysqli_fetch_row`, then you need to use `$row[0]` instead of `$row['Publish_on']`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

> mysqli_result::fetch_row -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an ***enumerated array***

```
<?php

  $id     = (int) ($_GET['postid']);
  $result = mysqli_query("SELECT Publish_on FROM `post_head` WHERE `post_id` = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
  $row    = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
  $date   = date_create($row[0]);
  echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');

?>
```

But if you still prefer to use `$row['Publish_on']` then use `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.